# Google Maps showing grey tiles on export

Tags: android, google-maps

I followed all the instructions on diffrent questions about this issue in SO, yet i didnt get to export my application which is based on google maps correctly.

when i debug my app on the device using eclipse the application works fine, but then when i export it, it doesnt show the map.

I did get my API key correctly:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:apiKey="API KEY HERE"
    android:clickable="true" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

and did ask for all premission outside the application tag and inside the menifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I also made sure Custom Debug keystore is the same as Default Debug keystore in eclipse build prefs.

I used the eclipse [export wizard](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard) and dont know what to do next...

What else could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate **signed apk** eclipse generates its own signed apk but you have to use your own.

and you need to use **release key**

To generate release key use **your app keystore file** instead of default **keystore**

Comment: those steps were way too complicated what to do after i got my signed APK using the wizard as in http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard